# Create model at runtime of web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Web API.  I have done a few sample projects creating a basic web api.  But what I am really wanting to try to d is create a model with parameters supplied to the Web API.

So for example, If I make the following call to my Web API

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "MYWebAPI",
    data: { modelName: 'Products', properties: 'ProductName, ProductID' },
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json;",
});
```

Can I have my controller create a model called Products with the properties of ProductName and ProductID.  Please be gentle.  I'm just trying to learn :)

I know I could just create a model like

```
 public class Product
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

}
```

Could I somehow create this dynamically?

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific.. by "create a model" do you mean write an entity to a database?  If you mean "create a model entity" do you mean using reflection to create the correct type and set properties (which in and of itself is vague for different reasons)?  If you mean create a dynamic type, you can always send JSON to the server and use dynamic types during deserialization..

Comment: @BobbyD Thanks for the reply.  I added a little bit more to my original question.  Hope this gets across what I am trying to ask.

Comment: Technically you *could* create such a model; but why?  How would any of your other code know how to interact with a class it doesn't know anything about?

Comment: Consider this.. not using a concrete type means the rest of your application will not know how to handle this entity.  If you plan on using this object in one more operations, why not create a view model class.. With the viewmodel as the argument for your controller, Asp.Net will map the properties you pass in to the properties of the object automatically

Comment: @BobbyD I am going to look into this.  Thank you for your input!